# Why excludesfile is not working?

Tags: ant, fileset

I have a list of class files to be excluded and i have added them in a file (say) exclude_class.txt as :

```
**/a/b/c/*.class
**/d/e/f/*.class
**/g/h/i/j/*.class
**/k/l/*.class
```

Now when I use `excludesfile` in `fileset` task it is not working:

```
<fileset dir=".">
    <include name="A/**/*.class"/>
    <include name="B/**/*.class:/>
    <excludesfile name="exclude_class.txt"/>
</fileset>
```

Please let me know what is the issue here. What should be the syntax of file to use in excludesfile task.

Answer (score 2):

`excludesfile` (and also `excludes, includes, includesfile`) is an *attribute* of `<fileset>` and not a *nested tag*. you may use it like this:

```
<fileset dir="." excludesfile="exclude_class.txt">
    <include name="A/**/*.class"/>
    <include name="B/**/*.class:/>
</fileset>
```

on the other hand, `<include>, <exclude>` are *nested tags* and may be used in the manner in which you've written.

as for the *syntax* within `exclude_class.txt`.. just make sure that there are **no leading / trailing spaces** in each line.

Comment: Thanks 'sunbabaphu' this worked for me. Can i use a comma separated list of files in excludesflie task?

Comment: No. it says *each line of this file is taken to be an exclude pattern.* on this page: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html .. so no commas, just line-breaks!

Comment: No i mean excludesfile="file1.txt,file2.txt" is this supported? or do i need to add one more fileset task?

Comment: the doc. @ https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html mentions **"the name of a file"**, so probably 1 file, but go ahead and try. maybe, it'll work